# logs data to elasticsearch server

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-lambda

I followed the article "Exploring images on social media using Amazon Rekognition and Amazon Athena" and everything is working as expected.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/exploring-images-on-social-media-using-amazon-rekognition-and-amazon-athena/

My question is: How do I stream the data to elasticsearch service?

I tried to add this code in the function

```
import base64
import requests
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth

host = '' # the Amazon ES domain, including https://
index = 'lambda-kine-index'
type = 'lambda-kine-type'
url = host + '/' + index + '/' + type + '/'

headers = { "Content-Type": "application/json" }

region = 'us-east-1' # e.g. us-west-1
service = 'es'
credentials = boto3.Session().get_credentials()
awsauth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key, credentials.secret_key, region, service, session_token=credentials.token)

# edit the function
        r = requests.put(url + tweet['id'], auth=awsauth, json=json.dumps(sentiment_record), headers=headers)
```

The function is downloaded from:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-bigdata-blog/artifacts/EyeOfCustomer/labelimage.zip

The problem is that requests module is not built-in. I am not sure how to add that in this function.
But I will like to know if there is any other way to add data to elasticsearch in this case.

Comment: Try to use - `from botocore.vendored import requests` instead `import requests`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Importing requests from botocore as suggested in comments did not work. But the following code worked once added to lambda function.

```
import urllib3
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
host_senti = 'https://search-xxx.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com/mysentiments/senti/'

# The line to actually add an entry to elastic
        http.request('POST', host_senti+str(tweet['id']), headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, body = json.dumps(sentiment_record) )
```